# pygtk: cannot set parent on toplevel widget

Tags: python, pygtk

I'm working on a project that has a glade GUI.

I need the main window to have 2 section, divided by a gtk.Hpaned widget (horizontal panes).

The left pane would have a tool-bar like layout of buttons, maybe 3 or more.

What I need is a way to create different windows and display them on the right pane of the main window. This way, when I click button 1, subwindow1 will appear in the right pane. Click button2, subwindow2 will appear on the right pane.

Instead of having windows pop-up left and right, I want to reparent them to the right pane of this gtk.Hpaned widged.

How do you do this in python with pygtk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you try this?

```
gtk.Widget.reparent(new_parent)
```

The reparent() method moves a widget from one gtk.Container to another.

Comment: Ok, That kinda sorta does the trick, but not exactly what I was looking for...

But I guess it will do, so I'll take it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating windows you could put a notebook in the right pane.  Then create all the previous windows as pages.  Click on the button can then show the appropriate page in the notebook.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using boxes for your panes. Start with a horizonatal Box that will essentially act as your main window:

```
hboxMain = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL, spacing=1)
```

then two vertical boxes for your panes:

```
vbox0 = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, spacing=1)
vbox1 = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, spacing=1)
```

then add whatever buttons you like to your panes:

```
btn0 = Gtk.Button()
btn1 = Gtk.Button()
btn2 = Gtk.Button()
```

```
vbox0.pack_start(btn0, False, False, 1)
vbox0.pack_start(btn1, False, False, 1)
vbox0.pack_start(btn2, False, False, 1)
```

(with a VERTICAL Box, pack_start will add the child widget you specify (btnN above) to the top of the box, and continue down as you keep calling pack_start. HORIZONTAL will go left to right.)

Then finally add your vertical boxes to the main horizontal box, and ultimately add the horizontal box to your main window.

```
hboxMain.pack_start(vbox0, False, False, 1)
hboxMain.pack_start(vbox1, False, False, 1)

win = Gtk.Window(title="Home")
win.add(hboxMain)
win.show_all()
```

It sounds like you want to add window widgets to the right-hand box. I can't answer if that is possible as I assume Window is more regarded as a higher level Container. I imagine it would make more sense to pack into the right side box some text boxes, etc. Not sure why you would want to add a Window widget. Go ahead and give it a try.